# Nginx catchall vhost doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I've already searched half the internet, but my nginx catchall config doesn't work for some reason. At the moment I've got 3 vhosts:

- One for my subdomain: *cloud.abc.com*
- And one for a subdomain of another domain: *mail.def.com*
- A catchall vhosts that looks like this (I just quickly wrote it):

  `server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      listen 443 default_server;
      listen [::]:443 default_server;
      root /var/www/default;
      return 404;
      #server_name _; <- doesn't work as well
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  }`

Whenever I try to access my servers IP address, it'll automatically redirect to *cloud.abc.com* and I don't know why. Shouldn't it be the catchall vhost, since it's the only one that has `default_server` in it? I've also tried *4abc.com* as `server_name`, since it would be the first in the alphabet then, but nothing.

Comment: What order of virtual hosts do you have? Try to set your default vhost first at the list. If you have different conf files for vhosts, add 000- prefix to your default.

Comment: Did you created symbolic link for the configuration? It would be helpful if you post some logs.

Comment: What do you mean with "order"? I just create my nginx configs in the _/sites-available/_ folder and create a symbolic link to _/sites-enabled/_ . I've already added a '1' as a prefix.
@Keshari Nandan Well, the access.log basically shows a 301 redirect, that's all I can see.

Comment: Do your tests use `http` or `https`? You have a default server for `http`, but you are missing the necessary directives to enable `https`.

Comment: I'm just using my IP, so that should be `http`.